# Memcache сессии

Tags: memcache

Использую memcache сессии.

```
php.ini
session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path = "tcp://127.0.0.1:11211"
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies =
session.name = PHPSESSID
```

Странно то, что на index странице если установить сессию то ее можно прочитать. А если на другой любой странице попробовать ее прочесть, то напишет что сессия не существует.

Comment: Приложение работало раньше? Стартуется ли сессия на остальных страницах? Примеры кода?

Comment: `> telnet 127.0.0.1 11211`  ?

Comment: проблема в том, что потребовалось установить memcache сессии, что бы вынести хранилище и использовать на демоне ratchet. Настроил php.ini, создал сессию на index странице, она читается, попробовал прочесть на другой странице, выдает что индекс не найден. Код приметивен, на index: session_start(); $_SESSION['qwerty'] = '123'; echo $_SESSION['qwerty'];  На другой странице: session_start(); echo $_SESSION['qwerty']; Куки читаются на обоих страницах.

Comment: Через telnet коннектится.

Comment: Попробуй  посмотреть попадает ли что то в memcache. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560150/get-all-keys-set-in-memcached

Comment: Показывает что есть item с названием сессии

Comment: А значение какое? 'get session_name'. Просто что бы убедиться что значения не пустые...

Comment: выдает просто end.

Comment: Правда там название с префиксом идет, а кука выдается без префикса. т.е на мемкеше qwerty8ucjvmptrajd3omvj7oa86n5 а кука выдается 8ucjvmptrajd3omvj7oa86n5

Comment: Это роли не должно играть. Похоже memcache  значения теряет... А если попробовать без сессии что то просто записать в memcache  а потом почитать?

Comment: `session.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211?persistent=1&weight=2&timeout=2&retry_interval=10"` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215323/php-memcached-session-not-working . Remove `tcp://`!